# Detecting the beginning of the line in a cell in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way for me to find the location of the beginning of line in a cell?

I want to encapsulate the label with HTML spans.

```
Cast Animation: 0.25 + 0.67
Cast Range: 575
Radius: 0 ( 375)
Self Damage: 75 / 100 / 125 / 150 ( 123 / 148 / 173 / 198)
Enemy Target Damage: 120 / 165 / 210 / 255 ( 168 / 213 / 258 / 303)
Allied Target Heal: 120 / 165 / 210 / 255 ( 168 / 213 / 258 / 303)
5.5 ( 4.675) 50
Can be cast on Spell Immune allies.
Cannot be cast on spell immune enemies.
Self damage pierces spell immunity.
Blocked upon impact, as primary and secondary target, therefore, Abaddon still loses health.
Can be disjointed by enemies and allies.
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `the location of the beginning of line in a cell`? 2. What is the data in your question? 3. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Sorry. Missed that one. 

This is what the input is

`Cast Animation: 0.25 + 0.67
Cast Range: 575`

Output is this: 
`<span>Cast Animation: 0.25 + 0.67
<span>Cast Range: 575`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You cannot detect the beginning of a line, but you can detect line breaks as `\n`

Then, you can encapsulate each line in `<span></span>` tags e.g. as following:

`="<span>"&regexreplace(A1,"(\n)","</span><span>")&"</span>"`

Hereby `A1` is the cell reference that you can obviously modify according to your needs.